# Is irradiation uniform in a large hollow enclosure in thermal radiation study?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation

[image]Consider a large hollow enclosure, the inner surface of which is kept at a temperature T. If we consider any imaginary differential surface area $dA$ inside the enclosure, will the irradiation remain the same no matter where I considered the surface area inside the enclosure?

In other words will G1,G2,G3,G4 be the same?

Comment: You are talking about a blackbody and the question is whether the shape influences the number of photons per cm-2?

Comment: The irradiation of what?

Comment: Irradiation due to the enclosure on any point inside the enclosure. I've added an image for reference.

Comment: What are G1, G2 etc meant to represent?

Answer (score 0):

If G1, G2 etc are meant to represent the net flux through a differential area, and if the system has been allowed to reach a perfect equilibrium, then each of G1, G2 etc. will be identically zero. If $G_1$, $G_2$ etc. represent the specific intensity at those points, then those will be identical and given by the Planck function. The Planck function depends only on the temperature of the radiation and the shape of the surrounding walls or the position within the volume have no influence.

The blackbody (or Planckian) radiation field is perfectly isotropic, so the flux passing through the area in one direction will equal the flux passing through in the opposite direction. This also means there is no net flux into or out of any closed surface within the volume.

If the interior radiation field is not Planckian, then the answer will depend on exactly what it is.